# Oracle join a table and fetch the data even if the data is present in second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `employee` and `employee_salary`.

```
select * from employee where branch_id = '001';

select * from employee_salary where branch_id = '001';

select *
from employee a,
     employee_salary b
where a.branch_id = '001' and a.empno = b.empno;
```

In the third sql, I need to fetch the values from employee table, even if there are no values in employee_salary.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use explicit LEFT JOIN

Comment: It's good practice to always do explicit joins. And those are so easy to convert to LEFT JOIN if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a left join (retrieves rows from employee table regardless if they have a match in employee_salary or not):

```
select *
from employee a
left join employee_salary b
on a.empno = b.empno
where a.branch_id = '001';
```

Comment: @Mihai, hope I'm not missing something here, but the where condition applies to the employee table (a) so it shouldn't do that transformation.

Comment: `and` without `where` will never give expected result